# "Раздвигающаяся" форма поиска

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте!

Хочу сделать форму поиска, чтобы она могла "раздвигаться" вниз, после нажатия "расширенный поиск" и появлялись дополнительные поля.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script>
    function show_hide() {
    if($('.show_field').is(':visible')) {
            $('.show_field').hide();
    } else {
        $('.show_field').show();
    }
    }
</script>
<form>
    <label>Введите слово для поиска</label>
    <input value="">
    <a onclick="show_hide();">Расширенный поиск</a>
    <div style="display: none" class="show_field"><label>Поле 1</label>
        <input value="Поле 1">
        <label>Поле 2</label>
        <input value="Поле 2">
    </div>
</form>
```

Или же еще проще

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#click').click(function(){
        $('.show_field').slideToggle();
    });    
});
</script>
<form>
    <label>Введите слово для поиска</label>
    <input value="">
    <a id="click">Расширенный поиск</a>
    <div style="display: none" class="show_field"><label>Поле 1</label>
        <input value="Поле 1">
        <label>Поле 2</label>
        <input value="Поле 2">
    </div>
</form>
```

Естественно подключить jquery.

Comment: А как лучше проверять отправленные данные в обработчике, т.е. пользовалель отправил форму простую или расширенную

Comment: if(isset($_POST['имя_поля_расширенного_поиска'])) {
   echo 'расширенный поиск';
} else {
   echo 'обычный поиск'
}

Comment: но есть вероятность, что пользователь не заполнит это поле в расширенном поиске, а другие заполнит

Comment: делайте проверки

Comment: Если даже он его не заполнить это поле прийдет пустое, мы проверяем не на empty(), а на isset(). isset() - проверяет наличие поля,а empty() - его содержимое.

Comment: alter_f4 СПАСИБО!

Answer (score 2):

Можно просто менять у блока(div) с дополнительными полями css-свойство `display`
сначала задавать `display: none;`
поле нажатия `display: block;`

Если хочешь, чтобы плавно раскрывался, используй jQuery. Почитать о нем можешь [здесь](http://anton.shevchuk.name/javascript/jquery-for-beginners/)